# Подскажите элемент управления

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2015

В Groove Music при воспроизведении аудиокомпозии есть стрелка (скорее всего Button) (Красным выделена), при её клике вылазит нижнее меню (Лазурным цветом на фото). А так же просто при перетаскивании по Y самого Grid. Скажите пожалуйста, может кто знает как это самому сделать можно такое меню, которое будет по клику на стрелку или по перетаскаванию Grid вылазить. Что-то на подобие SplitView, только снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Элемент управления - Accordion, аналог Expander (WPF)

https://github.com/brendankowitz/ZeroProximity.Accordion

Comment: А он не работает)